# Perfect numbers and powers of two

Tags: sequences-and-series, perfect-numbers

Given any even perfect number $p$ we may notice that the difference between $p$ and closest power of two is also a power of two.

Some examples:

$8-6 = 6-4 = 2$

$32-28 = 4 = 2^2$

$512-496 = 16 = 2^4$

$8192-8128 = 64 = 2^{6}$

$...$

$33554432-33550336 = 4096 = 2^{12}$

$8589934592 - 8589869056 = 65536 = 2^{16}$

...and so on.

So, the questions are:

1. Was this fact known before?
2. Could we find an even perfect number which breaks the sequence?
3. Is this sequence infinite?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. No. 3. Unknown. Every even perfect number is of the form $2^{p-1}\cdot (2^p-1)$, where $p$ is a prime, and $2^p-1$ is also a prime (a Mersenne prime). [And all numbers of that form are perfect.] And thus an even perfect number is of the form $2^{2p-1} - 2^{p-1}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer what is the proof of the statement that every even perfect number is of that form?

Comment: @user129901 Typo, you meant even perfect number (I suppose) but wrote even prime. Are you familiar with the sum-of-divisors function $\sigma$?

Comment: @DanielFischer yes i am familiar with it

Comment: @user129901 A proof of Euler's result that all ***even*** perfect numbers are in fact of the form (the form that Euclid knew), can be found online several places, for example [A proof that all even perfect numbers are a power of two times a Mersenne prime](http://primes.utm.edu/notes/proofs/EvenPerfect.html).

Comment: @user129901 As Jeppe Stig Nielsen kindly provided a link, I will not now post a proof here. If the linked proof isn't clear, ask for clarification.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen thank you i understood the proof

Answer (score 2):

I apologise for not looking at the date.  In any event I have never seen the perfect numbers expressed as sums of powers of 2, which is a surprise to me given how simple it is to prove.  If this is already known by all means let me know.  As a few examples we have:

$2^1(2^2 - 1) = 6 = 2^1 + 2^2$

$2^2(2^3 - 1) = 28 = 2^2 + 2^3 + 2^4$

$2^4(2^5 - 1) = 496 = 2^4 + 2^5 + 2^6 + 2^7 + 2^8$

$2^6(2^7 - 1) = 8128 = 2^6 + 2^7 + 2^8 + 2^9 + 2^{10} + 2^{11} + 2^{12}$

Just because I have never seen the perfect numbers expressed this way does not mean that I am the first to do so.  I would hate to think that I am merely reproducing what is already well known, so any help in this regards would be appreciated.  Many thanks for responding.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/) for mathematical equations.

Comment: Every positive integer is a sum of powers of 2.